# Setting Selected=True on each SelectList item does not affect rendered ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been messing around with this one all day and I'm at the last hurdle. Basically I've got a multiple select list on one of my forms which I'm populating with data from my database. I've got a 'Widgets' property defined in my model as a selectlist.

Then in the section where I bind properties from my database to my model, I've got linq expression which adds properties from another table to my selectlist. This is all working fine and I can use the result to correctly post back. However if I set the selected = true property in my linq statement nothing gets selected on the other end. So my question is why? All the other properties, id's etc.. are getting passed through fine.

My Model:

```
[DisplayName("Article Id")]
public int ArticleId { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Article Title")]
public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Article Body")]
public string ArticleBody { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Publish on Site")]
public bool Published { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Add to Featured Articles")]
public bool Featured { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Created Date")]
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
public int AuthorId { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Author")]
public string Author { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Modified Date")]
public Nullable<DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
public int OwnerId { get; set; }
public SelectList Widgets { get; set; }
```

My Controller (Relevent bit)

```
ArticlesModel Obj = new ArticlesModel
{
    ArticleId = row.ArticleId,
    ArticleTitle = row.ArticleTitle,
    ArticleBody = row.ArticleBody,
    Featured = row.Featured,
    Published = row.Published,
    Widgets = new SelectList(db.Query("SELECT * FROM [Widgets]").Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.WidgetName, Value = ((int)x.WidgetId).ToString(), Selected = true }), "Value", "Text")
};
Obj.SetGlobalProperties(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Application);
ViewData["Article"] = Obj;
```

and Finally the View

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Widgets, Model.Widgets, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "margin-left: -20px !important; width: 500px" })
```

Would really appreciate any help here - I've been pulling my hair out all day with something that on the face of it seems quite simple.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you are adding Selected true to all options its wrong

Comment: I realize that, it was just a test I'm going to be doing some logic for which id's to select later. For now there shouldn't be any harm in selecting them all since it's a multi select option anyway.

Comment: you want to show selected which one?

Comment: For each article I have a field called widgets with a JSON array of ids in it. Later on I'm going to deserialize that array into a list and do a '.contains' on it to get the desired selections. For now though I'm just concerned with why I can't get it to select at all.

Comment: see @C Bauer answer it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not mix the `available options` with the `selected options`.

You need to add another property for saving the `selected options` and change the `available options` type from `SelectList` to `SelectListItem[]`.

```
public SelectListItem[] Widgets { get; set; }
public int[] SelectedWidgets { get; set; } // depends on WidgetId type
```

Change it to `SelectListItem[]`.

```
Widgets = db.Query("SELECT * FROM [Widgets]")
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    { 
        Text = x.WidgetName, 
        Value = ((int)x.WidgetId).ToString(),
        Selected = true 
    })
    .ToArray()
```

**html**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedWidgets, Model.Widgets)
```

Comment: The additional property for `int[] SelectedWidgets` is correct and necessary for binding, but there is no need to change `Widgets` from `SelectList` to `SelectListItem[]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, nope, if the type is `SelectList`, the selected values that are supplied in `SelectListItem` are gone, `SelectList` 4th parameter accepts the selected values, see C Bauer answer, or the selected values need to be provided in `SelectedWidgeds`

Comment: @YuliamChandra, Yes, your correct if `SelectedWidgets` is not set.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you want for selectlist is:

```
new SelectList(items, data value field, text value field, **selected value**)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx

Edit: For any person who came here and has the issue and is wondering why this is, when you create a select list out of an IEnumerable, the selectlist isn't generating it's items based on (what you think is intuitive) the selectlistitems. You're just providing it with an object of type X and telling it to use properties Y and Z for datatextfield and datavaluefield respectively. The select list **does not** know that you provided it with a collection of selectlistitems not does it care. It wants to know what your selected values are when it is looking at object of type X with datavalueproperty Z.

Answer (score 1):

Change how you assign Obj.Widgets to the following:

```
var selectedValues = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

ArticlesModel Obj = new ArticlesModel
{
    ArticleId = row.ArticleId,
    ArticleTitle = row.ArticleTitle,
    ArticleBody = row.ArticleBody,
    Featured = row.Featured,
    Published = row.Published,
    Widgets = new MultiSelectList(
        db.Query("SELECT * FROM [Widgets]"), 
        "WidgetId", 
        "WidgetName", 
        selectedValues)
};
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this hasn't selected anything either. But it's a lot simpler than what I was originally doing.

Comment: How are you setting `selectedValues`? Which values are you trying to select? All of them? `selectedValue` needs to contain the `WidgetId` values.

Comment: It does contain WidgetId values at the moment I haven't done the logic for retrieving those so I've just done: var selectedValues = new List<int> { 2, 3 }; 2 and 3 correspond to the only rows I have in the Widget table.

Comment: Look at the HTML source when it's rendered in the browser. Are the `value` properties 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes they are, there's no selected attribute in the HTML source however.

Comment: Did you change your `SelectList` to a `MultiSelectList`?