# Passing parameters between a Controller and JavaScript in an ASP.NET Core MVC app?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with a view, controller and a small JavaScript file.  A JavaScript function gets called when the user clicks on an item in a listbox.  The JavaScript calls a function on the controller, the controller creates a SelectedListItem list and sets the values for 'Selected', 'Value' and 'Text'.  'Selected' is set to **true**.

What I noticed is when the JavaScript function receives the data, everything is correct but the 'Selected' field is set to **false**'  I am not sure how that can be.  Thank you for your help!

View

```
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.SelectedBaselines, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label" })
          @Html.ListBoxFor(x => Model.SelectedBaselines, new SelectList(Model.BaselinesList, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "baselines", @multiple = true, size = "10", style = "width:200px;" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.SelectedBaselines, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

[image]

Controller

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectedBaselines(string meterId)
{
  IQueryable<SelectListItem> baselines =
    from mlookup in _dbContext.MeterBaselineLookup.AsNoTracking()
    join baseline in _dbContext.MeterBaseline on mlookup.MeterBaselineId equals baseline.Id
    where mlookup.MeterId == Convert.ToInt32(meterId)
    orderby baseline.Id
    select new SelectListItem
    {
      Selected = true,
      Value = baseline.Id.ToString(),
      Text = baseline.Name
    };

  return new SelectList(baselines, "Value", "Text");
}
```

[image]

JavaScript

```
$('#meters').change(function() {
    var url = "/Meters/GetSelectedBaselines";

    $.getJSON(url,
        { meterId: $("#meters option:selected").val() },
        function(data) {

            $('#baselines option').prop('selected', false); // Clear selected baselines

            var len = $('#baselines option').length;

            for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {  
                $("#baselines option[value=" + i + "]").attr("selected", true);
            }  
        });
});
```

Comment: There is not point setting the 4th parameter in the `SelectList constructor`. It's ignored when binding to a model property because internally the `ListBoxFor()` method builds its own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the Selected property based on the value of the property your binding to. Therefore send a value as a 4th parameter that would be a condition and based on that, you can mark your item as selected.

Comment: Please do not repost your same question in different posts. I've closed your previous one as a duplicate of this one, since this one has a bit more information associated with it. In the future, edit your existing question to add information.

Comment: Chris, they are not duplicates but two completely different issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just return below

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectedBaselines(string meterId)
{
 IQueryable<SelectListItem> baselines =
from mlookup in _dbContext.MeterBaselineLookup.AsNoTracking()
join baseline in _dbContext.MeterBaseline on mlookup.MeterBaselineId equals baseline.Id
where mlookup.MeterId == Convert.ToInt32(meterId)
orderby baseline.Id
select new SelectListItem
{
  Selected = true,
  Value = baseline.Id.ToString(),
  Text = baseline.Name
};

return baselines ;

}
```

Reference link for related questions：

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714016/10201850
https://forums.asp.net/t/1382564.aspx?SelectListItem+losting+select+value+in+View+page

Answer (score 1):

The 4th parameter is meant to store the value being selected, kindly try:

```
return new SelectList(baselines, "Value", "Text",baselines[0].baseline.Id);
```

Or just this:

```
return new SelectList(baselines, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: I removed the fourth parameter and makes no difference.  (I actually added the fourth parameter just to see if  it would work.)